# How can I provide proof of ownership of a bank account?

Tags: canada, banking, bank-account, gambling

I set up a gambling account ended up making a large amount of money. I have verified my ID and proof of address and I want to withdraw, but I need a proof of ownership of the bank account that funded the gambling account:

> Proof of Payment: account ownership showing your deposit made to us:
>
> - Copy of a physical document, the original PDF file or a screenshot of your online banking pages showing your account number and your name as the account holder.

The problem is that when I set the gambling account up with my friend he just paid the deposit for both of us from his bank account. Our current plan is for him to add me onto his bank account so that I can get proof of ownership. Are there any alternatives to this and what would there be any consequences of adding me on and removing me as an owner after the money is withdrawn?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "gambling account"? Do you mean an account with a casino, or an online casino?

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest way of doing this be to get your friend to withdraw the money and then give you your share?

Comment: Could this be a scam?

Comment: Is this site legally operating in your jurisdiction? If yes, highly suggest you seek out guidelines / support from your provincial gambling authority to see if they have a FAQ about what such a site is / isn't allowed to ask from you. If no... you may be in a pickle.

Comment: The problem at the moment is that what you are trying to do is indistinguishable from money laundering.  Pay money in from one account.  Gamble with it - you win some, you lose some.  Then get your winnings paid out into a completely different account.

Comment: " I set the gambling account up with my friend he just paid the deposit for both of us from his bank account." is this a real-life friend that you gambled with in person at a casino or some friend you only know online?

Comment: You're explicitly doing something that the casino forbade: using someone else's money to gamble. Now you're trying to circumvent their detection mechanism. This smells like money laundering. You may get into legal trouble.

Comment: If it is a scam, the next step might be they ask you to pay a 'processing fee' for being able to withdraw it, and so on...

Comment: @Freiheit It is not a scam I have known the person in real life for years.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not someone you know well and in person, review some scam questions first [Why might a Fan Duel bettor want to launder his winnings through someone else's bank account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/149599/why-might-a-fan-duel-bettor-want-to-launder-his-winnings-through-someone-elses). OP commented that this is a real-life friend, so that does not apply here. I mention it only to help the next person with a similar question.

The gaming company is likely performing these checks to prevent theft or laundering. The account owner who funded the account should be the only person who can benefit from the winnings.

It seems like the easiest way to get money out is just for the friend you went in with to withdraw the money from the gaming account then give you your share.

Something you and your friend should do is to consider any tax implications. If he/she is the account owner, and their sole-owner account funded the gaming, and their sole-owner account withdrew the winnings, then any taxes or fees due will be paid by your friend.

Comment: I have already verified the account with my ID. I am scared if I try and change the account name and ID they will ban me and I won't be able to get any money out at all. Is this a valid concern or should I just contact them and ask to change my ID and personal info?

Comment: @NoahCristino I would *expect* they would at least owe you your money back, otherwise they would be stealing from you